# How do I tell what exception Xcode's Exception Breakpoint is breaking on?

Tags: xcode, debugging, xcode4

I've got the Exception Breakpoint added in Xcode 4, and it's breaking on a line where some kind of exception is being thrown.  But it's not logging any error information.  How do I tell what exception is causing the break if the app doesn't log anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exceptions are not logged per-se. When you see an exception being logged it's because the exception is being caught by a generic try-catch handler that logs it. This happens way later than the moment the exception is being thrown and at that point the stack has been unrolled and there's no more information on where it was thrown.

The breakpoint stops execution as soon as the exception is being thrown, before any stack unrolling or anything else happens. You should look at the stack and the stack trace to figure out what exception, where and why is being thrown.

Comment: I did, and there's nothing there.  It's breaking on a call to `[NSManagedObjectContext save]`.  The topmost frame on the stack is objc_exception_throw.  No information whatsoever on what exception is being thrown.

Comment: Depending on how the exception is being thrown it may be easier to figure out which it is in earlier frames. But if there's no way to do that, you can still find the exception object as a parameter to objc_exception_throw itself. However the details depend on your system. It will be in one of the registers. It used to be in `edx` on 32 bit intel builds and in `rax` on 64 bit intel builds. Not sure about iphone stuff, but it's there somewhere. Likely it'll be a register with a value that is a pointer and with the `isa` ivar at that address referring to an exception class.

Comment: Is it possible it's breaking on an exception that's being thrown and caught by the Core Data API, and that therefore can be ignored?

Comment: Possible. But I do not think Apple APIs use exceptions internally in that way. The general idea with Cocoa is that when an exception is thrown, the application shall eventually terminate. Catching an exception is not meant to be a way to solve the problem, just a way to terminate gracefully and notify the user of what has happened.